# Not able to download file with DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Getting error when downloading file with download manager android.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download
>   HTTP/HTTPS
>   URIs:file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0CD40428-2583-4AEB-B6F6-06696B77E861/tmp/com.example.testing-Inbox/Ebbill.pdf
>   at
>   android.app.DownloadManager$Request.(DownloadManager.java:429)

How to download this file using DownloadManager.

Comment: Where is that file? What is its uri/url? Where do you want to download it from? Show the used code.

Comment: As per [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager)  `DownloadManager` is a system service that handles long-running `HTTP/HTTPS` downloads. Your `URI` seems to be a `file-uri`